# Prove that $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\ a_n^2$ is convergent if $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\ a_n$ is absolutely convergent

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

Suppose that $\displaystyle\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\ a_n$ is absolutely convergent. How can we prove that $\displaystyle\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\ a_n^2$ is convergent?

Answer (score 10):

$$\lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{a^2_n}{|a_n|} = \lim_{n \to \infty} |a_n| = 0,$$
since $\sum |a_n|$ converges.  By the limit comparison test, $\sum a^2_n$ converges.

Comment: This doesn't work. For example, it's trivially true that if $\displaystyle \frac{\displaystyle\frac{1}{n!}}{\displaystyle \frac{1}{n}}\to 0$ but the Harmonic Series doesn't converge.

Comment: @Alex: That doesn't work as a counterexample.  I'm not concluding that the series consisting of terms from the denominator converges; I'm concluding that the series consisting of terms from the numerator converges.  That makes all the difference.  The fact that the limit of the ratios is $0$ means that the terms in the numerator are essentially smaller than the terms in the denominator.  Since the larger (denominator terms) series converges, so does the smaller (numerator terms) series.

Comment: @Alex: See, for example, [here](http://www.mathscoop.com/calculus/infinite-sequences-and-series/limit-comparison-test.php).

Answer (score 9):

Hints:

1) Convergence of an infinite  sum implies its terms tend to $0$.

2) If $  |a_n| \le 1$, then $  a_n^2\le |a_n|$.

3) Recall the Comparision Test for infinite sums.

Comment: hello can you explain how did you get $|a_n|<1$? did you use the geometric criterion? thnk you.

Comment: @Neophyte Eventually, $|a_n|<1$. This so since the terms of a convergent series must tend to zero.