# $\sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty |a_n|$ converges implies $\sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty |a_n|^2$ converges?

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Prove that $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\ a_n^2$ is convergent if $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\ a_n$ is absolutely convergent](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/255614/prove-that-sum-n-1-infty-a-n2-is-convergent-if-sum-n-1-infty-a)

If $\sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty |a_n|$ converges, the $\sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty (a_n)^2$ is also always convergent?

Comment: Yes. What did you try to prove it?

Comment: It's a cute question (+1)

Comment: @Did That was the problem. Did not find a way to prove it

Answer (score 9, accepted):

**Hint:**

1. If $\sum |a_n|<\infty$ then $a_n\to 0$
2. If $a_n\to 0$ then after some $n$ you have $a^2_n\leq |a_n|$ (why?)

Comment: you were faster ... (+1)

Comment: @Chris'ssister: my excuses

Comment: @Ilya Thanks for your suggestion. I now understand

Answer (score 7):

If $\sum |a_n|$ converges, then $|a_n|\to 0$, and thus for sufficiently large $n$, say $n>N$, $|a_n|<1$.

For such $n>N$, $|a_n|^2<|a_n|$, so $\sum |a_n|^2<\sum |a_n|$ and thus by comparison, $\sum|a_n|^2<\infty$.